# Unorderable types in "if" predicate

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def determineLetterGrade():
    global letterGrade, testAvg;
    if (testAvg <= str(100)) and (testAvg >= str(90)):
        letterGrade = "A";
    else:
        if (testAvg <= 89.99) and (testAvg >= 87):
            letterGrade = "B+";
        else:
            if (testAvg <= 86.99) and (testAvg >= 80):
                letterGrade = "B";
            else:
                if (testAvg <= 79.99) and (testAvg >= 77):
                    letterGrade = "C+";
                else:
                    if (testAvg <= 76.99) and (testAvg >= 70):
                        letterGrade = "C";
                    else:
                        if (testAvg <= 69.99) and (testAvg >= 67):
                            letterGrade = "D+";
                        else:
                            if (testAvg <= 66.99) and (testAvg >= 60):
                                letterGrade = "D";
                            else:
                                if (testAvg <= 59.99) and (testAvg >= 0):
                                    letterGrade = "F"
    # end determineLetterGrade function
```

Midterm project, creating functions, this is the function `determineLetterGrade`. Using `if` statements to determine a letter grade for the test average. When I go to run it, I get an error message:

```
if (testAvg <= str(100)) and (testAvg >= str(90)):
TypeError: unorderable types: function() <= str()
```

Comment: You should replace all your `else: if(... ` with `elif`s. Unrelated, but it would make your code much cleaner.

Comment: The error message says that `testAvg` is the name of a function, not a variable that contains a number.

Comment: And what is `testAvg`?

Comment: Do you have a function called `testAvg` declared somewhere?  As asides from your actual problem:  You might want to pass the average to check as a parameter to your function and just return the grade instead of setting a global variable.  Also, you might be able to save some indentation levels if you check out the `elif` statement

Comment: Plus  you don't need to do AND inbetween each if statement you already know the previous wasn't satisfied so will fall in the right branch example if > 90 'A' elif > 80 'B' etc

Comment: Why are you calling `str()` in the first `if`, not not in any of the rest? Is `testAvg` supposed to be a string or a number?

Answer (score 0):

The error is exactly what it says on the tin: the interpreter can't figure out which is larger when you hand it a function and a string. This means that `testAvg` is the name of a function elsewhere in your code. You need to actually call it, with any appropriate arguments, and have it `return` the proper value. Call it once, and then save it to a local variable like `average_score = testAvg()` (pass arguments as needed). You can then make a comparison... but then you shouldn't be casting the other values to strings. Leave them as integers.

Also, you should restructure your code to replace the repeated `else..if` blocks with a structure that uses the `elif` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because you usually do not want to compare two different types of objects, in this case a function and a string. First, fix testAvg so that it's a number instead of a function, as I assume that's what you want to compare. You are likely setting testAvg to be a function instead of what that function returns.

```
if (testAvg <= str(100)) and (testAvg >= str(90))
```

Should be:

```
if (testAvg <= 100) and (testAvg >= 90)
```

There are a lot more things that can be improved in your function such as not using global variables (returning the string instead) using `elif` instead `else if`, correcting the indentation, and conditional chaining (e.g. above could be written as `90 <= testAvg <= 100`). But this should address your particular question.

Comment: The error message says that `testAvg` is a function, not a number.

Comment: A. `testAvg` is a function. B. You can indeed compare strings to each other. In fact, in Python 2 you can compare strings to numbers.

Comment: A. Corrected B. We know the OP is asking about Python3 because otherwise there would be no error so Python2 is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

1.) You could be just simply a bit careless, because there is a few row something like this in your code:

```
def testAvg():
    return anything
```

and you missed to add `()` to the function name `testAvg` and so you get the **function itself** and not **its return value**.

2.) Or was misled by some rows like this:

```
def Anyfunction():
    anything

testAvg = Anyfunction
```

Thus you thought `testAvg` a simple variable.

3.) Or it happened a simple careless redefinition of the variable testAvg by a function with the same name:

```
testAvg = anyvalue

def testAvg():
    anything
```

In the third case you have to fix the code.
In the first two case you have to fix your code like this:

```
if (testAvg <= str(100)) and (testAvg() >= str(90)):
```

in every single relevant row.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you exactly what's wrong. You're comparing a function to a string.

Additionally, you're not handling a few cases:
- What if the input value is between 79.99 and 80, for example? What if it's 79.995?
- What if you get an input `> 100` or `< 0`?

Stylistically, you're also doing a bunch of ridiculous stuff. You shouldn't be declaring globals in the function, you should be passing arguments to the function, and `testAvg` (at least, the value you pass in) should be a floating point number, not a function. And you should be using `elif`, not `else: if ...`. And you shouldn't be casting things to strings. You should be comparing floating point numbers to either ints or other floats. You're also using semicolons, which is rather gauche in python. Scripting languages generally omit semicolons.

Since your midterm is over and this can't help you cheat, here's a working example (it's somewhat optimized, but if you work through reading it and understand what it's doing, you'll be a better programmer for having done so. Wonder, for example, why there are two `'A'` characters in that array, and why I'm using integer division).

```py
from sys import argv

def determineLetterGrade(testAvg):
  if 0 <= testAvg and testAvg <= 100:
    grade_range = int(testAvg // 10)
    if grade_range < 6:
      grade = 'F'
    else:
      grade = 'DCBAA'[grade_range - 6]
      if grade != 'A' and (testAvg % 10) >= 7:
        grade += '+'
    return grade
  else:
    raise Exception("Grade out of range")

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print determineLetterGrade(float(argv[1]))
```

On a final, passing note...
Your grade calculation is a bit wonky. I used it in the above, but in most grade systems with a '+', it's also possible to get a '-'.